# error on Decrypting AES. The input data in not a complete block. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, aes

Good day. 
I'm using encrypting a text using AES then save the encrypted byte to a txt file.

--

### code of btnencrypt in form1.frm

```
Dim aes_CryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = AesCryptoServiceProvider.Create.CreateEncryptor(aesKeySet.Key, aesKeySet.IV)
Dim textBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtb_plaintext.Text)

Dim encrypted() As Byte
using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
     using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(textBytes, aes_CryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.write)
          using textStream as New StreamWriter(csEncrypt) 
               swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
          End Using
          encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
          csEncrypt.close()
     End Using
End Using

dim textDirectoryPath as String = "C:\encryptText.text"
using textFilestream as new Filestream(textDirectoryPath, filemode.create)
     textFilestream.write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length)
     textFilestream.close()
end using
```

--

### code of btnDecrypt in form2.frm

```
Dim aes_CryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = AesCryptoServiceProvider.Create.CreateEncryptor(aesKeySet.Key, aesKeySet.IV)

Dim textBytesToDecrypt() As Byte = File.readAllBytes("C:\encryptText.text")
dim plainText as string = nothing

using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream(textBytesToDecrypt)
     using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(textBytes, aes_CryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.read)
          using textStream as New StreamReader(csEncrypt) 
              plainText = textStream.readToEnd()
          End Using
          csEncrypt.close()
     End Using
End Using
```

--
if i click the decrypt button i got an error message saying "the input data is not a complete block"
what seems to be im doing wrong?

Comment: There are other errors here I think. You should be passing msEncrypt as the first parameter to the CryptoStream constructor since otherwise msEncrypt never gets anything written to it.

Comment: I don't see the file opened as truncated file either. If it already exists, the data will be appended to the end of the file.

Comment: It seems a little asymmetric to use File.ReadAllBytes but not File.WriteAllBytes.  But the first thing to check is how many bytes do you think you wrote, and how many did you read.  FWIW, the correct answer will be a multiple of 16.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have forgotten to call `swEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock()`. I don't have much VB experience but the error means that the encrypted data is not padded to a full block size. My C# code looks similar to yours except I am writing bytes and then calling `FlushFinalBlock()`

See the example in C#:

```
private IEncryptionResponse Encrypt(byte[] data, IKey key)
{
    try
    { 
        using (var symmetricAlgorithm = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            symmetricAlgorithm.GenerateIV();
            byte[] iv = symmetricAlgorithm.IV;

            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var encryptor = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(key.RawKey, iv))
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                            var encryptedBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                            return Convert.ToBase64String(iv.Add(encryptedBytes));
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                           symmetricAlgorithm.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new EncryptionException("Encryption error", e);
    }
```

}

Comment: With `using`, the resource should be automatically closed. And if it is automatically closed, it should be automatically flushed. And if it is automatically flushed, I'd assume that `FlushFinalBlock` is called as as a consequence.

Comment: The StreamReader ctor used in the question causes the CryptoStream to be disposed when the StreamReader is, so FlushFinalBlock is implicitly called already.  (aka "@MaartenBodewes is correct")